# How to generate a TABLE in js with the flexibility to width/height/row/column

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to put in options to be able to input column/row/width/height for my Javascript table..but can't seem to get it work. I have absolutely no coding background.. just got into this course 1 month ago..

I tried looking up everywhere but I can't make sense of what is happening..

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
  <p>No. of Cols: <input type="text"  name="cols" id="cols" value="3" /> 
    </p> 
    <p> No. of Rows<input type="text" name="rows" id="rows" value="3" />  
      Sample Cell Data <input type="text" id="sample" />  </p>
    <p> Cell Height (in pixels)<input type="text" id="height" />  

     Cell wdith in pixels<input type="text" id="wdith" />  </p>


    <Button onClick="generate()">Generate Table</button>


    <button onClick="deleteTable()">Clear Table</button>

    </form>

    <hr />

    <p id=generatedTable> </p>
</body>

<script>

    function generate()
    var myTable = document.getElementById("generatedTable");
    var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
    table.border='1';

    var tableBody = document.create Element('TBODY');
    table.appendChild(tableBody);


    for (var y=0; y<num_rows; y++)
    {
        var num_rows = document.getElementById('rows').value;

        tableBody.appendChild(tr);
        var num_cols = document.getElementById('cols').value;
        for (var x=0; x<num_cols; x++)
        {
            var td = document.createElement('TD');


            td.width = 10; td.height = 10;  td.align = "center";
            var cellID = "cell [" + x + ", " + y + "]";

            td.setAttribute("id",cellID.toString());

            td.addEventListener("click", function(){cellClicked(this);});
            // ... research and add other mouse events!!!

            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Cell " + x + "," + y));
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
    }
    myTable.appendChild(table);
}

}



</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to build something from scratch? If not, then take a look to jQuery and the jQuery plugin DataTable. It can save you a lot of development hours.

Comment: Yes... It is part of my homework lol.

Comment: Well, part of the problem is that your code is invalid. You can't just wrap all of your HTML in a `<script>` tag...

Comment: Well, there are a few things that you need to fix first. Your HTML tags are all mixed up. For example, you have the `<html>` inside the `<script>`. Second, move your code at the end of the page (inside the body). Remember that JavaScript needs all the DOMs loaded prior to be able to access them.

Comment: You can put your JS code inside a self executing function 
`(function() { /* code here */ })();`. This will ensure that everything in your page is loaded (all DOMs) prior the JS code running.

Comment: My bad, first time using this website I wasnt so sure on how to insert my codes

Answer (score 1):

In the code, you provided the `num_rows` and `num_cols` is the number of column/row,  width/height is related styles; so, you don't want to do it in javascript, you can provide some styles like this:

```css
.custom-width{
/* some  style */
}
```

then in your code after creating a `td`:

```
var td = document.createElement('TD');
td.classList.add('custom-width')
// do other stuff and append it
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution to your problem is to use Bootstrap 4 grid; it permit to create responsive tables using only div as rows and columns. In this way you can manage very easily width and height with col-size class.

Install: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/

Bootstrap grid: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

`var num_rows` and `var num_rows` should be out of both the for loop.

`tr` should be declared inside the first `for loop` because you cannot append to it till it is declared.

for simplicity, I have set the `num_rows` and 'num_rows' to 5.

for guidance in future how to work with tables you can refer 
[Traversing an HTML table with JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Traversing_an_HTML_table_with_JavaScript_and_DOM_Interfaces)

```js
var element = document.getElementById("div1");
debugger;
var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
var table= document.createElement('table')
table.appendChild(tableBody);

var num_rows = 5;
var num_cols =5;
for (var y=0; y<5; y++)
{
    //document.getElementById('rows').value;
   var tr =document.createElement('tr')
     //document.getElementById('cols').value;
    for (var x=0; x<5; x++)
    {
        var td = document.createElement('TD');


        td.width = 10; td.height = 10;  td.align = "center";
        var cellID = "cell [" + x + ", " + y + "]";

        td.setAttribute("id",cellID.toString());

        td.addEventListener("click", function(){cellClicked(this);});
        // ... research and add other mouse events!!!

        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Cell " + x + "," + y));
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
     tableBody.appendChild(tr);
}
//myTable.appendChild(table);
element.appendChild(table)
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

td
{
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. But I needed to put in those adjustable input options like rows/column how should I do that?

Comment: The main thing I don't understand is the append.... and all those loopings

Comment: https://www.dofactory.com/tutorial/javascript-loops#section3 look at the link and understand why do we use for loop

Comment: JavaScript loops are used to repeatedly run a block of code - until a certain condition is met. When developers talk about iteration or iterating over, say, an array, it is the same as looping.